# Django - Query_set returns an empty arraylist when it is ran in the test

Tags: django, testcase

I am trying to run a TestCase on my model.

I already have a MySQL database (specifically MariaDB through a HeidiSQL GUI) created and connected with the respective data inside for this project.

My test.py code is as follows:

```
class TestArrivalProbabilities(TestCase):
    def test_get_queryset_test(self):
        print("Hello Steve!")
        i = 1
        self.assertEqual(i, 1)
        l = [3, 4]
        self.assertIn(4, l)

    def test_get_queryset_again(self):
        query_set = ArrivalProbabilities.objects.all()
        print(query_set)
        n = len(query_set)
        print(n)  # Print each row
        bin_entries = []
        bin_edges = []
        for i in range(n):
            print(query_set[i])
            if query_set[i].binEntry is not None:
                bin_entries.append(query_set[i].binEntry)
            bin_edges.append(query_set[i].binEdge)
        print(bin_entries, bin_edges)

        hist = (numpy.array(bin_entries), numpy.array(bin_edges))
```

However, the output in the terminal is this:

```
(venv) C:\Users\Steve\uni-final-project>python manage.py test     
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
<QuerySet []>
0
[] []
.Hello Steve!
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.016s

OK
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

I have tried to figure out why the MySQL database I built isn't being used. I read up that Django creates a Test 'dummy database' to use on a test and then tears it down after but am I missing something really obvious?

I don't think it is a connection issue as I have pip installed mysqlclient. And I have tried to use the https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/queries/#creating-objects but I still get the same result.

I have read the documentation but I am struggling with certain aspects of it as I am new to software development and this course is quite a steep learning curve.

I checked to see if this question wasn't asked before but I couldn't see any answers to it. Apologies in advance if it has been answered somewhere.

Any help in the right direction or a solution is much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you should read something related to testing not django's creating-objects. When you want to test your code usually there are some approaches regarding database. In official [django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/testing/overview/#writing-tests) its shows how to deal with database instances. Simply when you start your test it creates a test database and runs your testcases. For that you can use a `setUp` function
add this and try again please:

```
class TestArrivalProbabilities(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        ....
        ArrivalProbabilities.objects.create(...)
        ArrivalProbabilities.objects.create(...)
        ....
```

after this part you no longer will see empty queryset.
You can also use [fixtures](https://realpython.com/django-pytest-fixtures/)

Comment: Thanks for your help with this! I was using the setUp function but I mistakenly put quotation marks in front of the numbers (I know that was dumb) and because of that I was getting an empty query_set. 

But now thankfully it's working and I can use it to for loop to build a histogram.

Thank you again for helping

Comment: its ok to make mistakes :) glad that you solved it :)